# Why do Merckle trees use nibbles

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie, yellow-paper

In Appendix D of the yellow paper for Ethereum, it describes the Modified Merkle Patricia Tree, and states:

> Any series of bytes may also trivially be viewed as a series of nibbles, given an endian-specific notation; here we assume
>   big-endian. Thus:

[image: Latex of formula]

What is the purpose of this translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows you traverse the tree one "hex value" at a time. (Or: Each character in a hash or address is one nibble in size.)

- 1 byte => `0xFF`
- 1 nibble => `0xF` (we're really concerned with just the `F`)

The path from the root node to a leaf node describes a hex string - e.g. an account address or transaction hash. Each layer you descend in the tree equates to a hex character. A nibble is basically just a single hex character, whereas a byte is two. You *could* use a byte, and just use half of it, but then the tree would take up twice as much space.

Comment: Thanks! A really concise way to describe it. Sounds like its the same as why we wouldn't use two letters for each edge in a radix tree.